# SQL Server Management: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I'm using SQL Server Management to create a database (fot a work in the university), I'm trying to insert new values into a table but recieving error.

The two relevant tables I created are:

```
create table ballotBox
(
    bno integer,
    cid numeric(4,0) references city,
    street varchar(20),
    hno integer,
    totvoters integer,
    primary key (bno)
);

create table votes
(
    cid numeric(4,0) references city,
    bno integer references ballotBox,
    pid numeric(3,0) references party,
    nofvotes integer
);
```

I've entered first the values to ballotBox (as well as for the table 'city' and 'party'):

```
insert into ballotBox values 
    (1, 1, 'street1', 10, 1500),
    (2, 1, 'street2', 15, 490),
    (3, 1, 'street2', 15, 610),
    (4, 1, 'street2', 15, 650),
    (5, 2, 'street3', 10, 900),
    (6, 2, 'street3', 55, 800),
    (7, 2, 'street4', 67, 250),
    (8, 2, 'street4', 67, 990),
    (9, 2, 'street5', 5, 600),
    (10, 3, 'street1', 72, 1000),
    (11, 3, 'street6', 25, 610),
    (12, 3, 'street6', 25, 600),
    (13, 4, 'street2', 3, 550),
    (14, 4, 'street7', 15, 500),
    (15, 5, 'street8', 44, 1100),
    (16, 5, 'street9', 7, 710),
    (17, 5, 'street10', 13, 950);
```

And then I tried to enter values to votes:

```
insert into votes values
    (1, 1, 200, 100),
    (1, 11, 210, 220),
    (1, 1, 220, 2),
    (1, 1, 230, 400),
    (1, 1, 240, 313),
    (1, 1, 250, 99),
    (2, 1, 200, 55),
    (2, 10, 210, 150),
    (2, 10, 220, 2),
    (2, 1, 230, 16),
    (2, 1, 240, 210),
    (2, 9, 250, 54),
    (3, 9, 200, 234),
    (3, 9, 210, 123),
    (3, 1, 220, 8),
    (3, 1, 230, 87),
    (3, 1, 240, 76),
    (3, 1, 250, 6),
    (4, 1, 200, 135),
    (4, 1, 210, 246),
    (4, 17, 220, 7),
    (4, 1, 230, 18),
    (4, 1, 240, 44),
    (4, 1, 250, 66),
    (1, 2, 200, 373),
    (1, 2, 210, 12),
    (1, 2, 220, 3),
    (1, 2, 230, 74),
    (1, 2, 240, 58),
    (1, 2, 250, 272),
    (2, 6, 200, 139),
    (2, 6, 210, 2580),
    (2, 2, 220, 6),
    (2, 2, 230, 73),
    (2, 2, 240, 7),
    (2, 2, 250, 99),
    (3, 2, 200, 15),
    (3, 2, 210, 68),
    (3, 2, 220, 12),
    (3, 2, 230, 12),
    (3, 2, 240, 15),
    (3, 2, 250, 25),
    (4, 2, 200, 7),
    (4, 2, 210, 245),
    (4, 2, 220, 8),
    (1, 0, 0.0, 361),
    (4, 2, 240, 67),
    (4, 2, 250, 144),
    (5, 2, 200, 123),
    (5, 2, 210, 76),
    (5, 2, 220, 15),
    (5, 2, 230, 158),
    (5, 2, 240, 76),
    (5, 2, 250, 132),
    (1, 3, 200, 152),
    (1, 3, 210, 517),
    (1, 3, 220, 0),
    (1, 3, 230, 267),
    (2, 3, 200, 87),
    (2, 3, 210, 134),
    (2, 3, 220, 4),
    (2, 3, 230, 11),
    (2, 3, 240, 256),
    (2, 3, 250, 76),
    (3, 3, 200, 105),
    (3, 3, 210, 132),
    (3, 3, 3220, 3),
    (3, 3, 230, 24),
    (3, 3, 240, 254),
    (3, 3, 250, 12),
    (1, 4, 200, 61),
    (1, 4, 210, 54),
    (1, 4, 220, 5),
    (1, 4, 230, 19),
    (1, 4, 240, 1),
    (1, 4, 250, 47),
    (2, 4, 200, 17),
    (2, 4, 210, 23),
    (2, 4, 220, 0),
    (2, 4, 230, 64),
    (2, 4, 240, 11),
    (2, 4, 250, 149),
    (1, 5, 0200, 187),
    (1, 5, 210, 88),
    (1, 5, 220, 1),
    (1, 5, 230, 255),
    (1, 5, 240, 12),
    (1, 5, 250, 373),
    (2, 2, 500, 245),
    (2, 5, 210, 120),
    (2, 5, 220, 9),
    (2, 5, 230, 19),
    (2, 5, 240, 234),
    (2, 5, 250, 5),
    (3, 5, 200, 107),
    (3, 5, 210, 18),
    (3, 5, 220, 11),
    (3, 5, 230, 54),
    (3, 5, 240, 378),
    (3, 5, 250, 243);
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__votes__bno__1920BF5C". The conflict occurred in database "Voting", table "dbo.ballotBox", column 'bno'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You're trying to insert a row with the value `0` for `bno` but this does not exists in the ballotbox table. The faulty row is `(1, 0, 0.0, 361),` Voting to close this question as it's a data error and not programming issue.

Comment: There is another issue though: the values you're trying to insert in `votes.pid` overflow the `numeric(3,0)` column. It should probably be an integer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to insert

```
 (1, 0, 0.0, 361),
```

in `votes` table have FK `bno` 
there are no record corresponding to 0 in `ballotbox` table
please remove this line from votes statement then insert

Answer (score -2):

The relationship between two tables is not correct.

Make it so:

```
create table votes
(
    cid numeric(4,0),
    bno integer,
    pid numeric(3,0),
    nofvotes integer
    foreing key cid reference city(cid)
    foreing key bno reference ballotbox (bno)
    foreing key pid reference party(pid)
);
```

Comment: No, the syntax is correct. The column name can be omitted in the references clause. Also, you misspelled `foreign`.